# Javascript Pushing elements inside a loop, doesn't affect the array outside the loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, loops, mongoskin

I have an empty array that I want to push items onto, inside a loop. Once outside the loop, the array losses all information

```
var result = [];
        users.find({}, {username: true, isOnline: true, uniq: true, _id: false}, function(err, cursor) {
            cursor.each(function(err, item) {
                result.push(item);
                console.log(result); //every iteration the array shows fine
            });

            console.log(result); //array is empty
        });

        console.log(result); //array is empty
```

Comment: What exactly is `cursor`? does it's `each` method work asynchronously? If not, then your explanation of what is happening doesn't make sense. I wouldn't expect `.each` to be asynchronous.

Comment: `each` must be asynchronous. Where does that method come from? You should specify what framework/library you are using.

Comment: Is this MongoDB stuff?

Comment: This is MingoDB and it says on their site that cursors has the each function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using [Mongoskin](https://github.com/kissjs/node-mongoskin), you can use the `toArray` method to convert the cursor to an `Array`, which seems to be what you want. **Check this out:**

http://www.hacksparrow.com/mongoskin-tutorial-with-examples.html

```
db.collection('stuff').find().toArray(function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
});
```

**So your code would look like this:**

```
var result = [];
        users.find({}, {username: true, isOnline: true, uniq: true, _id: false})
        .toArray(function(err, cursor) {
            // cursor is now an array. forEach is sync.
            cursor.forEach(function(item) {
                result.push(item);
                console.log(result); //every iteration the array shows fine
            });

            console.log(result); // Should not be empty now
            // Add more code in here, if you want to do something with
            // the result array
        });
        // Still empty, because find is async.
        // Your code should go inside of the users.find call
        // and not here
        console.log(result);
```

This is something you'll be dealing with a lot with node. For async code, the rest of your code must go inside of the async calls. You can keep dealing with callbacks, or use Promises, for instance.

Comment: Or if you do not like CB or promises you can use Async/waterfall library

Answer (score 0):

This could be because `users.find` and `cursor.each` functions may be asynchronous, so your second console.log is executed before the execution of `cursor.each` and your third console.log is executed before `users.find`

Comment: second console.log statement is executed in the callback of ```users.find```

Comment: this would only be the case if the each function were asynchronous

Comment: aw04 the each function is probably async, in Javascript it's forEach to iterate sync over an array.